# Vue Only in Single Laravel blade view

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

i'm trying to understand is there any way that we can make vue instance in single blade file only when needed??
i want to import library to vue but, i know that it should be compiled by webpack..

is there any way that i can import the library to my main.js and only use each component that i want, in any blade?
i mean like this:

Main app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
```

and inside blade file with the script tag :

```
<script>
     const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components:{Multiselect} ,
        data :{

        },           
        methods:{

        },
        mounted:function(){
        },
    });
</script>
```

???

Comment: yes you can do it like that.... there is a nice video tutorial here: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step

Comment: thanks,i will check that..